# gulp default, Task never defined: default, Please check the documentation for proper gulpfile formatting

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I checked out my project on a new machine and get an unsatisfying console output.

**Console Output**
gulp default
Using gulpfile ...\gulpfile.js
Task never defined: default
Please check the documentation for proper gulpfile formatting

**gulp -v**
CLI version 1.2.2
Local version 4.0.0-alpha.2

**Settings**
Node interpreter: nodejs-6.9.2\node.exe
Gulp package: node_modules\gulp-4.0.build

**Gulp File Content**

```
'use strict';
var gulp = require('gulp');
var del = require('del');
var path = require('path');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var gulpPromise = require("gulp-promise");
var gulpPromiseAll = require('gulp-all');
var merge = require('merge-stream');
var through = require('through2');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var async = require("async");
var Rx = require('rx');
var chok = require('chokidar');
var deleteEmpty = require('delete-empty');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var webserver = require('gulp-webserver');
var historyApiFallback = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

/* A few functions like this */
var yadda1 = function() {
    return yadda9("yadda", yaddayadda);
};

/* A few tasks like this */
gulp.task('build', function(){
    return gulpPromiseAll(
        yadda1(),
        yadda2(),
        yadda3()
    ).then(
        function() {
            console.log("yadda");
        }, function(err) {
            console.error("yadda:", err);
        }
    );
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('build', 'serve', function(done) {
    console.log("Default task that cleans, builds and runs the application [END]");
    done();
}));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is definition of the 'serve' task? I only see the 'build'. Did you try run the default task without 'serve'?

Answer (score 3):

I just had this problem.

We both are using browser-sync, and a task related to browser-sync is where the problem was in my code, so there's a good chance that you have the same problem (and possibly in your other gulp tasks as well), but can't say for sure because you didn't share the tasks' code.

**The problem:**

In gulp 3.x you could write code like this:

```
gulp.task('watch', () => {
    gulp.watch('./dev/styles/**/*.scss', ['styles'];
    ...
});
```

You can't in gulp 4.x.

**The solution:**

You have to pass a function instead of the name of a task in these cases. You can do this by passing a gulp.series() function. The above code becomes:

```
gulp.task('watch', () => {
    gulp.watch('./dev/styles/**/*.scss', gulp.series('styles'));
    ...
});
```

Try making this change wherever applicable. Worked for me.